# Read Only equivalents for other inputs in html/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, reactjs

### Background

- I have a basic CRUD form/webapp. It happens to be react/redux but for our purposes it doesn't matter much. I'm pretty sure this is an HTML question.
- The form itself represents a 'legal document' a bit, and multiple users log in to view/edit it at once. (think kinda google docs ish)
- Some users can only view, some can edit.

### The Problem

- I want my edit users to be able to use the form elements (input/select etc) to modify the data, and my view users to see that same data as similarly as possible.
- I want my view users to be able to copy and paste from the screen.
- The disabled and readOnly flags won't quite work.

### Failed Solutions

- **Disabled**: With a little CSS magic is looks perfect, and the view users don't get onclick reactions they shouldn't. BUT you can't copy and paste the text. This is the current state of the app.
- **ReadOnly**: Isn't supported by many of the inputs I have (select, radio, etc) although it's pretty much perfect for text and texarea.

### The Question

Is there a reasonable or elegant way to achieve behaviour like ReadOnly but across all HTML elements?

### Clarifications

- Since the current view of the page is exactly what I want my view users to see (it's made to look like a paper form a little) If I chose to use 'view mode' spans for my components or a 'view page' mode I would end up having a to make them look as much like my current inputs as possible. It feels weird/bad to try and make a precise recreation of what I have out of spans and divs instead of making what I have behave correctly. Still... it's the backup plan.
- We are using all kinds of inputs. Selects and dates and checkboxes oh my. Text and Texarea are well behaved, but the rest get less well behaved.

Comment: One idea is to present viewers with a page that displays the values (i.e.  no inputs).

Comment: I would just replace the elements. They should not have to look like inputs either, because they are view-only anyway. Regular spans should be fine for most cases.

Comment: What are you trying with regard to copy/pasting?? I made a simple input and selected text,  copy / pasted no problem.

Comment: @devlincarnate Creating a view version is the issue I'm seeking to avoid. I'd end up with what feels like unneeded dupe code. At that point I'd be building a Select react comp with a readonly flag that actually acts like how I want it via an if statement inside which... doesn't feel polite. *shrug* may be the only option though?

Comment: this.Print() is not an answer but can get you half way through

Answer (score 2):

Readonly propperty is only supported by input and textarea, check [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=readonly).

As it has been said in a comment, replace input elements by others that don't allow insert data and re-style the elements to look similar if that's what you want.